# A finite automaton accept no string

Tags: automation, automaton

How can a finite automaton over(0,1) doesn't accept any string? I only can think of

```
s->a->q->F
```

Where the final state F is empty set. Is that true please?

Comment: Better to post this on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most likely yes. Why "most likely"? Well.

Mathematically, an FSA is a 5-tuple `(Sigma, S, s0, delta, F)`, where

- `Sigma` is the alphabet,
- `S` is the set of states,
- `s0` is the initial state,
- `delta` is the state-transition function,
- `F` is the set of accepting states.

Since you fixed `Sigma`, there are only four places where it can go wrong. If you create your FSA by hand, you of course create one

- that has no states
- that has no initial state
- in which not all states are accessible
- that has no accepting states

If we assume a well-formed FSA (meaning `S` is not empty and `s0 in S`, all states are accessible), which is the case if you create it from e.g. a regular expression with a library like [foma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foma_%28software%29), then yes: the only way for the FSA to not accept any string is to have no accepting states.